# Force multiple Applications in the "Open with..."

Tags: macos, file-association

I would like to force Lion to show both Excel and TextEdit as applications in "Open with..." dialog. I currently have Excel set as the default for .dat files but occasionally I just need to glance at the header of the file which is much quicker with textedit. It is a Space separated text file.  On that same vein, is it possible to have the finder recognize the file as text so I can preview it? Even if I set the default app to TextEdit it won't preview. 
I did find [On OS X, how do you change a file's "Kind"?](https://superuser.com/questions/263311/on-os-x-how-do-you-change-a-files-kind) but it doesn't quite address my request. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As for Quick Look, see: [Make OS X's Quick Look work for custom file extensions](http://superuser.com/questions/230204/make-os-xs-quick-look-work-for-custom-file-extensions)

Comment: Checked out @slhck link and did it slightly differently. Edited info.plist in /System/Library/QuickLook/Text.qlgenerator to include public.dat, public.cr1, public.csi and now preview works. I did have to give myself permission to edit the file (Get Info...Sharing & Permissions...Everyone- R&W)

Answer (score 1):

Checked out the link from @slhck and did it slightly differently. 
Edited `info.plist` in `/System/Library/QuickLook/Text.qlgenerator` (right click...Show Contents) to include `public.dat`, `public.cr1`, `public.csi` and now preview works. I did have to give myself permission to edit the file (Get Info...Sharing & Permissions...Everyone- R&W) and I have XCode installed so I used property list editor to add the additional UTIs to Text.qlgenerator.