# "Kind" of .R file incorrectly displayed as "Rez Source" instead of "R Source File"

Tags: macos, mac, file-association, xcode, rstudio

I am a R user new to MacOS. I found that the "Kind" of .R files are shown as "Rez Source" instead of "R Source File", even after I set the default app for the file as Rstudio.app ([See the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f9sB.png). Interestingly, the icon is correct).

I checked the Info.plist for Rstudio.app, as suggested in [On OS X, how do you change a file's "Kind"?](https://superuser.com/questions/263311/on-os-x-how-do-you-change-a-files-kind). Everything seems to be correct there ([See the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5qsx.png)). So I doubt whether the document types defined by Xcode.app is overriding the document types defined by Rstudio.app, although the latter is my current default app for opening .R file. ([Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ldrx.png) for Xcode.app's Info.plist) But this possibility cannot explain why the icon is the correct Rstudio icon while only the "Kind" column is incorrect.

Does anyone have an idea about how to let the "Kind" column correctly display the document type defined by my current default application?

Comment: R was used by [Rez](http://preserve.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.14/14.09/RezIsYourFriend/index.html) which was on the Mac 20+ yrs ago. Today Rez is one of the [system declared UTIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259). Am not sure if you can override it but if you can it's with [a custom UTI](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47319/how-can-i-make-os-x-recognize-new-file-extensions).

Comment: I have a similar question - the file is identified correctly, but if I open the Macos search to search for R files, I don't see "R source file" in the options, only "Rez". I would like to add "R source files" to the list of Kinds for the purpose of searches.