# Change Kind of file OS X

Tags: macos, filesystems

I have a file whose `Kind` value I would like to change from `Document` to `Folder`.

The file was once upon a time a `Folder`. (In fact, a folder that was locked, though I don't know if that has any bearing on the `Kind`.)

The existing [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/263311/on-os-x-how-do-you-change-a-files-kind) seems to be answered regarding p-list edits and I don't see that this is relevant to my problem. If it is, apologies, and could you help me understand further?

Comment: If you Get Info on the item what is its name & extension? Some folder types are specifically displayed by the OS as though they were files. An application is one, such as your photos library are another.

Answer (score 0):

Adding certain [file extensions](https://eclecticlight.co/2017/03/14/bundle-package-library-or-folder/) (such as `.help`, `.app`, `.pages`) to a folder will make it appear as if it were a file. You can either remove the extension from the name, or simply open it as a folder by right-clicking and selecting 'Show Package Contents':

[image: Show Package Contents in macOS Finder]